# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have not started an Objectify context

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, junit, objectify

I am trying to take a test driven development approach to building a Java based app running on App Engine, but I am having difficulties getting the setup working.

My servlet

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

/* This is the servlet */
@WebServlet(name = "GroceryServlet", value = "/grocery")
public class GroceryServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GroceryServlet.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    log.info("context init");
    ObjectifyService.init();
    ObjectifyService.register(Grocery.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().println("Hello Kitty");
  }

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException {
      BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
      String line = null;
      StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
      }
      String jsonString = stringBuffer.toString();
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
      log.info("JSON "+ jsonString);

      Grocery grocery = new Grocery();
      grocery.setName((String) json.get("name"));
      grocery.setQuantity((Integer) json.get("quantity"));

      ofy().save().entity(grocery).now();

      log.info("JSON name "+ grocery.getName());

      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.getWriter().println(jsonString);
    }

}
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My unit test

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;

import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Closeable;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Unit tests for {@link HelloAppEngine}.
 */
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class GroceryServletTest {
  private static final String MOCK_URL = "/grocery";
  // Set up a helper so that the ApiProxy returns a valid environment for local testing.
  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
  private Closeable closeable;

  @Mock
  private HttpServletRequest mockRequest;

  @Mock
  private HttpServletResponse mockResponse;

  private StringWriter responseWriter;
  private GroceryServlet servletUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    helper.setUp();

    ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory(
      DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
        .setHost("http://localhost:8081")
        .setProjectId("enduring-trees-259812")
        .build()
        .getService()
      ));
      closeable = ObjectifyService.begin();

    //  Set up some fake HTTP requests
    when(mockRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn(MOCK_URL);

    JSONObject grocery = new JSONObject();
    grocery.put("name", "Beer");

    Reader inputString = new StringReader(grocery.toString());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputString);
    when(mockRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(reader);

    // Set up a fake HTTP response.
    responseWriter = new StringWriter();
    when(mockResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(new PrintWriter(responseWriter));

    servletUnderTest = new GroceryServlet();
    servletUnderTest.init();
  }

  @After public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    closeable.close();
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void doGetWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    servletUnderTest.doGet(mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // We expect our hello world response.
    assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        .contains("Hello Kitty");
  }

  @Test
  public void doPostWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
    reqObj.put("name", "Beer");
    reqObj.put("quantity", 5);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(reqObj.toString());

    when(mockRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(reqObj.toString())));

    servletUnderTest.doPost(mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // We expect our hello world response.
    assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        .contains(reqObj.getString("name"));
  }
}
```

The test fails with the following error message

> [ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time
>   elapsed: 0.103 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp.GroceryServletTest [ERROR]
>   doPostWritesResponse(mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp.GroceryServletTest)
>   Time elapsed: 0.078 s  <<< ERROR! java.lang.IllegalStateException: You
>   have not started an Objectify context. You are probably missing the
>   ObjectifyFilter. If you are not running in the context of an http
>   request, see the ObjectifyService.run() method.   at
>   mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp.GroceryServletTest.doPostWritesResponse(GroceryServletTest.java:109)

which is caused by this line ofy().save().entity(grocery).now() in my servlet. When I remove it, the test is run without errors.

I have tried to follow different approaches to resolve this error found here on stackoverflow but without luck.

How should the test/app be setup to be able to develop it using a test driven approach? What I am looking for is a way to be able to write the unit test first and then the actual application. But how to succeed?

(Disclaimer, I haven't worked with Java in over a decade)

**UPDATE**

ServletContext file

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

@WebListener
public class GroceryContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private ServletContext context;
    private Closeable closeable;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.context = event.getServletContext();

        ObjectifyService.init();
        this.closeable = ObjectifyService.begin();
        ObjectifyService.register(Grocery.class);
        System.out.println("Context initialized");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
      try {
        this.closeable.close();
      } catch(IOException ioe) {

      }
    }
}
```

Unittest file

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;

import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

/**
 * Unit tests for {@link HelloAppEngine}.
 */
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class GroceryServletTest {
  private static final String MOCK_URL = "/grocery";
  // Set up a helper so that the ApiProxy returns a valid environment for local testing.
  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
    new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
  private Closeable closeable;

  @Mock
  private HttpServletRequest mockRequest;

  @Mock
  private HttpServletResponse mockResponse;

  private ServletContextListener contextListener;
  private ServletContext context;

  private StringWriter responseWriter;
  private GroceryServlet servletUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    helper.setUp();

    contextListener = new GroceryContextListener();
    context = mock(ServletContext.class);

    //  Set up some fake HTTP requests
    when(mockRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn(MOCK_URL);

    JSONObject grocery = new JSONObject();
    grocery.put("name", "Beer");

    Reader inputString = new StringReader(grocery.toString());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputString);
    when(mockRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(reader);

    // when(mockRequest.getServletContext()).thenReturn(context);

    // Set up a fake HTTP response.
    responseWriter = new StringWriter();
    when(mockResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(new PrintWriter(responseWriter));

    servletUnderTest = new GroceryServlet();
  }

  @After 
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void doGetWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    servletUnderTest.doGet(mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // We expect our hello world response.
    assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        .contains("Hello Kitty");
  }

  @Test
  public void doPostWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    contextListener.contextInitialized(new ServletContextEvent(context));

    JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
    reqObj.put("name", "Beer");
    reqObj.put("quantity", 5);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(reqObj.toString());

    when(mockRequest.getReader()).thenReturn(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(reqObj.toString())));

    servletUnderTest.doPost(mockRequest, mockResponse);

    // We expect our hello world response.
    assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        .contains(reqObj.getString("name"));
  }
}
```

Servlet file

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

/* This is the servlet */
@WebServlet(name = "GroceryServlet", value = "/grocery")
public class GroceryServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GroceryServlet.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().println("Hello Kitty");
  }

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException {
      BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
      String line = null;
      StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
      }
      String jsonString = stringBuffer.toString();
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
      log.info("JSON "+ jsonString);

      Grocery grocery = new Grocery();
      grocery.setName((String) json.get("name"));
      grocery.setQuantity((Integer) json.get("quantity"));

      ofy().save().entity(grocery).now();

      log.info("JSON name "+ grocery.getName());

      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.getWriter().println(jsonString);
    }

}
```

Now I am getting a "com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated" error when running the test, so looks like I am on the right way. Would I store the datastore credentials in the web.xml and then pass them to the context similar to

```
ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory(
      DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
        .setHost("http://localhost:8081")
        .setProjectId("enduring-trees-259812")
        .build()
        .getService()
      ));
    ObjectifyService.factory().register(Grocery.class);
```

**New Update**

I upgraded to Junit5 and rewrote the entire test to this

```
package mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.util.Closeable;
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.factory;
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;

import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.testing.LocalDatastoreHelper;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp.util.TestBase;

import mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp.domain.Grocery;
import mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp.domain.GroceryList;

public class MyFirstTest extends TestBase {

  // Maximum eventual consistency.
  private final static LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
      new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
          .setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100));

  Closeable closeable;

  @BeforeAll
  public static void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
  }

  @AfterAll
  public static void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUpEach() {
    ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory(
      DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()));
    closeable = ObjectifyService.begin();
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void tearDownEach() {
    closeable.close();
  }

  @DisplayName("Test MyFirstTest.testAddition()")
  @Test
  public void testAddition() {
    assertEquals(1 + 1, 2);
  }

  @DisplayName("Testing testGroceryList()")
  @Test
  public void testGroceryList() {
    factory().register(GroceryList.class);

    GroceryList list = new GroceryList("Weekend Beer List");
    Key<GroceryList> k1 = ofy().save().entity(list).now();

    assertEquals(1+1, 2);
  }
}
```

It is deliberately kept in a single file for now. But for some reason, the datastore cannot find the emulator that is running when the test is run. I am getting a `Datastore Unauthenticated` error.

I ran `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` and `$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)` before running the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `ObjectifyService.init()` twice, but you only called `begin()` on the first (abandoned) factory.

You call `init()` in your `setUp()` method, which initializes the static `ObjectifyFactory`. You then open a session on that factory with the `ObjectifyService.begin()` call.

At the end of your `setUp()` you call `servletUnderTest.init()`, which also calls `ObjectifyService.init()`. This replaces the static `ObjectifyFactory`. When you next execute your servlet and call `ofy()...`, you're using a factory that has not started a session.

Take a look at the code for `ObjectifyService`. It's quite literally just a few lines of code to wrap a static `ObjectifyFactory` instance.

If you have more than one servlet, this code will not work well in production either - you only want to initialize and register your classes once. I recommend doing this with a `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post with how I understand your suggestion. And yes, there will be more than 1 servlet accessing the datastore

Comment: Don't call `begin()` in your `ServletContextListener`. In your test harness, you need to fundamentally do the same thing that the container is doing - except that instead of `ObjectifyService.init()` (no args), you need to call it with the datastore service. You almost certainly want a new init() for every test run, but also a begin()... outside of your code. Pretend you're the ObjectifyFilter.

Comment: Do you know og any good references that I can check? I havent found any that shows how to use objectify with servlets

Comment: I can't point you at anything directly, but this is Java 101 stuff - look at the impl of the ObjectifyService and you should be able to figure out how to build a test harness around it. Alternatively, look at the Junit5 harness in the Objectify source code - your app should do pretty much the exact same thing.

Comment: When I look at https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup it tells me to use the contextlistener to initialize ObjectifyService. I know it's probably different when it's done in a unit test, but still, it may be 101 but would be nice with some documentation :) And it's also not quit clear when looking at https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/4694b11532e6a7ff357d4c1d78b0b80b8aca4b1d/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/BasicTests.java

Comment: Take a look at `TestBase` and the registered Junit5 extensions. You can actually use the existing extensions as-is, but since you're on Junit4 you'll have to adapt them.

Comment: So it's something like this https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/util/ObjectifyExtension.java that I should be aiming for I guess

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: Looks like I got it down, but my test can't find the datastore emulator

Comment: When you use DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance(), you're telling the sdk to connect to production instances. Look at how the `LocalDatastoreExtension` and the `ObjectifyExtension` interact - the LDE instantiates a new helper, and the OE gets the service instance from the helper to pass to Objectify's `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

The core of test-driven development revolves around five steps, which you repeated throughout the software development life cycle.

**Test-driven development life-cycle:**

1. Write the test
2. Run the test (without implementation code, test does not pass)
3. Write just enough implementation so the test passes
4. Run all tests (test pass)
5. Refactor
6. Repeat

By following this steps you can create a TDD implementation for your application.

There is no specific way for Google Cloud to do beside the steps I have specified above.

As specified in your error, you can see that you have not started an Objectify context, and you are missing the ObjectifyFilter.

Here is a [implementation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-test-driven-list) of a list in Java, which follows the TDD, which may be helpful to clear some of your concerns.

Comment: That part I get, but I can't find an example showing me how to fix that

Comment: You can use @ Before/@ After in conjunction with ObjectifyService.begin() to start the requests. However, this is probably not actually how your tests will work.

A dirt quick around, you can fake it this way: 
* My @ BeforeMethod starts an objectify context (ObjectifyService.begin())
* My @ AfterMethod closes the objectify context
* That bit of code I used to use to complete() requests now simply closes the existing context and opens a new one.

Comment: I have the ObjectifyService.begin() inside a @Before method, but I still get the same error